# how to use Newsfeed in sharepoint foundation site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I had SharePoint foundation and I need to use the NewsFeed.

So how can I make the web part available outside of MySites?

Comment: You will have to add newsfeed webpart to any page where you need it.See this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78227/how-to-add-newsfeed-webpart-to-sharepoint-2013

Comment: i didn't found Site Feed  in my site setting .The problem could be the SharePoint foundation? maybe it dosent support teh feature ?

Comment: Are you checking in the rootweb of the site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in order to use the social feature you need the SharePoint Server 2013.

- Requires SharePoint Server
- My Site Host must be deployed

Because their is no UPA/Mysite in SPF so you cannt use it as far i know.

If you are using the team site then Site feed feature will available. Check the feature comparison here: http://florianlaumer.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-standard-vs-enterprise-vs-foundation-feature-comparison-matrix/

Comment: So do you have any idea how can I proceed. Do I need to Create and delete posts and retrieve the social feed by using the JavaScript object model in SharePoint 2013?? like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164025.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can activate it by following these simple  steps:

1. At the top of the site, click Settings   > Site settings.
2. From the Site settings page find Site Actions then under it click Manage site features.
3. From the list of feature, find Site Feed then click the Activate button (if not yet activated).
4. Go back to your Site homepage and you should now see the Newsfeed link  added from the left navigation panel. If you cannot see it, try to refresh the page. (Or Edit Page and add the webpart which is listed under Social Collaboration (Site Feeds))

Comment: in my page _layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx  there is no Site Feed to activat it. and i am in the root site

Comment: Go to the root site collection site feature manage page.

Comment: yes i am in the root site collection. and i dont see it