# SiteFeed WebPart Not Displaying- Sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, newsfeed, sitefeed

I am trying to add the newsfeed/sitefeed on the root site. I don't see the webpart available under social collaboration as [this thread suggests](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78227/how-to-add-newsfeed-webpart-to-sharepoint-2013/160878#160878).

I followed the instructions and the sitefeed is active in the site settings. This is the root site so I don't see why it wouldn't show up. All I see is Site Users.

Are there suggestions out there? If I remember right, it was there one day, and gone the next. I'm new to SP, but I am tasked with getting it set up for my employer (I'm a web designer).

Sharepoint 2013 Team Site, Office365

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It might be that scripting capabilities are not switched on in your tenant (these are actually off by default). When this is the case, there are bunch of web parts that are not available, including the site feed.

The following explains both what features are not available with scripting disabled, and what you need to do to enable them.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f